# Why the facebook iframe app-take-too- much time to load?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I got an issue with my fbapp is not loading quickly means it take time to load a app.
Even I have used gzip to reduce text size and also reduce image size.
Then also it take 10-12 seconds to load. Here is live fb app .

1. I have also optimize my database.
2. I have also optimize my CSS and JavaScript files.
3. For reducing image size I used http://www.smushit.com/ysmush.it/
4. I am using graph API for creating the fbapp.

By doing all this it reduce the time but then also it take 10-12 seconds to load my fbapp.

App Link :: http://apps.facebook.com/giftoramalive

Comment: for me it just takes 1-2 seconds. could be either a slow server or you got a slow internet connection?